# javascript object literal instantiation

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am new to js oop and i dont understand how i can do this.

i have

```
var Cadastro = Object.create(QForm);
var options = {
    myInstanceName: "Cadastro",
    dependentListsMode: "one",
    defaultButtons: ['enter-query', 'new']
}
Cadastro.initForm(options);
```

then i have QForm.js

```
var QForm;
QForm = {
    initForm: function (parms) {       
        $.extend(this, parms);        
        var frmObj = $(this.formId);
        this.userRestrictions(parms);       
        $(this.currentForm).find("a[data-form-action]").hide();
        this.clearForm();
        this.disableFields();
    },
```

The problem is that if i have e object in the same page , **this.currentForm** have the value of the latest intantiated object .

QForm.js is very extense file with lot of methods. How can i manage this. Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting `this.currentForm`?

Comment: You seem to be confused between objects, instances, and classes.

Comment: this.currentForm is in options, ive cut it because there was to much properties. Not confuse about objects or classes or instances. But Robusto you are right, qform is an object not a class

Comment: QForm is object literal and i have to use a constructor. thats it?

Comment: It is actually important what exactly do you do with `this.currentForm`, in general the approach works, see my answer.

Comment: Also it would be good if you reproduce your issue on a small self-contained example, you can start with code from my answer and extend it just to show the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general your code works, it uses `Object.create` to create new instances based on the `QForm` prototype and new instances do not share the properties, here is a short working example:

```js
var QForm;
QForm = {
    initForm: function (parms) {       
        $.extend(this, parms);        
        this.frmObj = $(this.formId);
    }
};

var cadastro = Object.create(QForm);
var options = {
    myInstanceName: "Cadastro",
    formId: "CadastroForm",
    dependentListsMode: "one",
    defaultButtons: ['enter-query', 'new']
}
cadastro.initForm(options);

var formTwo = Object.create(QForm);
var options = {
    myInstanceName: "FormTwo",
    formId: "test",
    dependentListsMode: "one",
    defaultButtons: ['enter-query', 'new']
}
formTwo.initForm(options); 

alert(cadastro.formId);
alert(formTwo.formId);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you run it, you will see `CadastroForm` and then `test`, so two instances created based on the QForm have different `formId` properties.

Comment: Though it's hard to tell what is wrong from what the OP posted, this should be helpful

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos check my comments to the answer and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you want to get help with the specific problem, you should create the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos Once you have this example, just edit your question and put all the details and example into it, also check the [whole 'asking' help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), there are some useful tips about asking good questions.